# Referencing .NET Core Class Library from Class Library (Windows)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is it possible?

Can we mix .NET Core Libraries with Windows Projects like "classic" class libraries, WPF, WinForms...?

Comment: You can't unfortunately, but I'm looking forward to someone answering with a nice workaround. Although it will defeat the purpose of it being cross-platform. At that point you could just use the framework. Probably you can use .NET core from non-CoreFX but not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross platform code is achieved by using .NET Standard class libraries, which can be used by both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

You can read more about how this is supported here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard